# Is there any way to specify a typehinted Pytorch DataLoader?

Tags: python, types, pytorch, type-hinting, pytorch-dataloader

Say I have the following:

```py
class SomeClass:
   def some_function(dataloader: DataLoader):
       for idx, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
           ... do something with batch ...
```

I would like to type the dataloader such that I can show through function parameter typehinting what format I expect `batch` to have. For example, I would like to have `batch` be of type `Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]` or I would like to type it `Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, CustomObject]`. Is there any way in which I can specify this?

I thought that maybe it would be possible through an AbstractClass inheriting DataLoader and then somehow specifying a type, but I'm not sure how that would look.

Comment: `I can show through typing what format I expect`, you want to print the type of batch while iterating through the batch?

Comment: No I would like to see the expected type in the parameter type, so like `def some_function(dl: DataLoader[Tensor, Tensor, CustomObject])`, such that other coders can see what is expected of them when they want to use the function.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that this is currently supported, nor possible.

For more details, see:

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/83347
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/83421#pullrequestreview-1073262797

I partial solution is to declare the dataset as:

```
class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset[MyCustomType]):
    ...

dataloader = Dataloader(MyDataset,...)
```

Although this will not allow you to infer types when doing `batch = next(iter(dataloader))`, at least you'll get some information e.g. by hovering the `dataloader` variable if you're using VSCode or some other IDE.

Answer (score -1):

I know that take some time from this starts, but, in this cases (not supported yet) I belive the better option should be just point as `object`:

```py
....

t: torch.Tensor = torch.arange(6, dtype=torch.float32)
data_loader: object = DataLoader(t)

....
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).